# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser " Character Issue

Tags: php, html, dom

1. I got my data from database as  like zkjxhvzkjxcvhnzxv"""!^!^!
2. used dd() for double check if i can get the data from database (i can)
3. **The problem is** output i can see is as following in my html: zkjxhvzkjxcvhnzxv
4. After the character " i can't implement the value into my html element, including "

Here are my codes :

```
$value = "zkjxhvzkjxcvhnzxv"""!^!^!";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<input type="text" value="'.$value.'">');
echo $html;
```

A second way to do it but nothing has changed :

```
$value = "zkjxhvzkjxcvhnzxv"""!^!^!";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<input type="text" id='myID'>');
$input = $html->getElementById('myID');
$input->setAttribute("value", $value);
echo $html;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not escaped double quotes in a string delimited by double quotes? How about that?

Comment: Yes i realized the problem after i posted. What do you offer ?

Comment: Learn the basics? Character escaping 101, etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i escape the characters, i lose them. But you can use addslashes() method for removing them.

Here's the answer for my situation :

```
$value = "zkjxhvzkjxcvhnzxv"""!^!^!";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load('<input type="text" value='.$value.'>');
echo $html;
```

Change is :

```
value='.$value.' instead of value="'.$value.'";
```

Hope this helps anyone.